# No Matching Function for call to Ultrasonic:Ultrasonic(int,int)

Tags: sensors, arduino-ide

Good Day! I am trying to code the distance of Ultrasonic Sensor but the problem is it gives me this error. Any idea? Please help.

```
#include <Ultrasonic.h>

// HR-SC04 SENSOR
#define TRIGGER_PIN   5
#define ECHO_PIN      6

Ultrasonic ultrasonic(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

// Global variables
int lastDistance = 0;
int thisDistance = 0;

void loop()
{
  // Copy over last distance
  lastDistance = thisDistance;

  // Get new this distance
  thisDistance = ultrasonic.Ranging(CM);

  if (outlierCheck(lastDistance, thisDistance)) {
    Serial.println("Outlier found: " + String(thisDistance));
  } else {
    Serial.println(String(thisDistance) + " cm");
  }

  delay(10);
}

// Check for significant jumps and outliers in sensor reading
bool outlierCheck(int lastDistance, int thisDistance) {

  // if the difference between measures is greater then 20cm, outlier found
  if ((lastDistance - thisDistance) > 20) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: look at the demo code that comes  with the library

Comment: I did already but it still give me this error "Ultrasonic ultrasonic(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN);"

Comment: the error messages tell you where the problem is ..... take another look at the demo code

Answer (score 1):

You are very likely to have confused the libraries.

When using your code with the library at https://github.com/JRodrigoTech/Ultrasonic-HC-SR04, the code compiles perfectly fine. The constructors match up with your code.

```
//Constructor 1
Ultrasonic(int TP, int EP);
//Constructor 2
Ultrasonic(int TP, int EP, long TO);
//methods.. (used in your source)
long Timing();
long Ranging(int sys);
```

I think you have installed this Ultrasonic library: https://github.com/ErickSimoes/Ultrasonic. It has the same header file and class name but the class is constructed differently

```
//Constructor 1
Ultrasonic(uint8_t sigPin) : Ultrasonic(sigPin, sigPin) {};
//Constructor 2
Ultrasonic(uint8_t trigPin, uint8_t echoPin, unsigned long timeOut = 20000UL);
//Note that a constructor with only 2 arguments is not directly visible
```

You should go into the Arduino IDE and uninstall your current "Ultrasonic" library from the library manager. Then download the zip file from the first given github repository and add that ZIP file to your libraries.

Alternatively of course, you can use the second library and its correct example code.

Also note that your Arduino IDE 1.0.6 is extremely outdated, current one is [1.8.5](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/software)